# In python how am I supposed to, after reading the file into a 2D list, using a function, not let the 2D list empty

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, file-io, user-defined-functions

I read in a text file, with a format:
ola,2
ola,4
ola,6

And i read this file in using the reading function that removes all the spare elements in the list:

```
import csv

def read(name,practicef):
    temp=[]
    name=name+".txt"
    practicef = list(csv.reader(open(name,"r")))
    print(practicef)
    print(len(practicef))
    temp=practicef
    practicef=[]
    for item in temp:
        if item!=[]:
            practicef.append(item)
            print(practicef)
    return practicef
```

And then when I wanted to compare the elemnts in the list to my password, the list was empty, I am just wondering why it did this and how i could avoid it.
The whole code together as it comes in the sequence is:

```
import csv

def read(name,practicef):
    temp=[]
    name=name+".txt"
    practicef = list(csv.reader(open(name,"r")))
    print(practicef)
    print(len(practicef))
    temp=practicef
    practicef=[]
    for item in temp:
        if item!=[]:
            practicef.append(item)
            print(practicef)
    return practicef



practicef=()
name="lollington"
read(name,practicef)
use=input("use")
pw=input("pw")
print(len(practicef))

for i in range(0,len(practicef)):
    print(use,pw)
    print(practicef[i][0],practicef[i][1])
    if use== practicef[i][0] and pw == practicef[i][1]:
        print("successful login")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a bit hard to follow what you want to do, however you actually don't use the results of your function.

does

```
practicef = read(name,practicef)
```

get you closer to where you want to be?

here is my output after that change (added a bit extra on the prints so it's easier to see where they are from):

```
in read [['ola', '2 ola', '4 ola', '6']]
len in read 1
[['ola', '2 ola', '4 ola', '6']]

use: ola

pw: 2
outer list len after fcn call: 1
uid ola pw 2
ola 2 ola
```

Comment: YES IT WORKS PERFECTLY NOW, THANK YOU